# How to prove for string of triplets that it is a Regular Language?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, proof-techniques

Let **Σ<sub>2</sub> = {0, 1}**, and define **Σ = Σ<sub>2</sub><sup>3</sup>**. Informally, **Σ*** is the **set of triples** of the form **(a, b, c) where a, b, c are single binary digits**.
Consider a string **s ∈ Σ*** : it is a sequence of such triples. Have to “verify” binary addition of numbers in the first two coordinates by checking that it is equal to the third. Let A be the language of such triples such that the concatenation of the first coordinates, as a number, and the concatenation of the second coordinates, as a number, sum to be equal to the third.

For example, if **w = (0, 1, 1)(1, 1, 1)(0, 0, 1)(1, 0, 1)**, this is encoding **0101<sub>2</sub> + 1100<sub>2</sub> = 1111<sub>2</sub>**,
which is false; therefore, **w ∉ A**. How to prove A is Regular ?

Only thing I could think of is somehow has to prove for Reversal is Regular and then this could be proved, but no further idea.

Comment: Simulate addition with carry. Two states should suffice.

Comment: Not getting your point ! Simulate addition with carry. NFA for addition - two states would be enough fine. But missing somethings I guess.

Comment: Actually I was thinking of a DFA.

Comment: yeah DFA is fine. But not able to understand .

Comment: It's easier to read the bits LSB to MSB.

Comment: Okay lets simplify . So i will make a DFA for the addition of Binary Numbers but I will use LSB to MSB configuration. So far good. I was also thinking this way , By reversal I meant the same thing. So if I could do that does it mean that original language in Question is Regular as the reversal is regular ?

Comment: The class of regular languages is closed under reversal. Hopefully you learned that in class.

Comment: Yes learned that in class. Do i need to take some special care for triplet sequence in my case ( the question ). w = (0, 1, 1)(1, 1, 1)(0, 0, 1)(1, 0, 1)  ?

Comment: They're nothing special. Just an alphabet. Perhaps it helps if you thought of them as ABCDEFGH instead of triplets.